# PySpark, Error calling saveAsTextFile

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

this is mi first attempt with Python. I'm trying to use python with Apache Spark.
This is what i want to do:

```
l = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/dataset.txt")
l = l.map(lambda x: map(int, x))
```

then i use cartesian function to obtain all possible combination of elements

`lc = l.cartesian(l)`

now for every couple i apply a function:

```
output = lc.map(lambda x: str(x[0]) + ";" + str(x[1]) + ";" + str(cosineSim(x[0], x[1])))`
```

my objective is to obtain strings like:

```
element1; element1; similarity
element1; element2; similarity
...
```

and so on..

when i call output.first() this is my output:

```
[45, 12, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 7];[45, 12, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 7];1.0
```

this is a string, indeed if i a do:

```
s = output.first()
type(s)
<type 'str'>
```

but if i execute output.collect() or output.saveAsTextFile(path) i have this error:

```
15/02/13 06:06:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 61.0 (TID 183, 10.39.127.148): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 107, in main
process()
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in process
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 227, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <lambda>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. This works for me: 
a = '[45, 12, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 7];[45, 12, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 7];1.0'
aa = sc.parallelize(a)
aa.saveAsTextFile('test2')                                                                         Can you try?

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be an error in this formula:

> l = l.map(lambda x: map(int, x))

Can you check that the l RDD always has values (no '')? If it doesn't, you get a typical Python error:

*>  In [32]: int('')*

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 int('')
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Moving forward, keep in mind that **map** are lazy evaluations which means that they are not computed until the next action (collect and save are actions) is instructed.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the help!
` l = l.map(lambda x: map(int, x))`
has values: [45, 12, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 7, 7]
and if i execute type(l.first())  the output is a list

type(l) is a <class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>